# creatorUserRecordID.recordName contains "__defaultOwner__" instead of UUID shown in Dashboard

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckrecord

Downloading a `CKRecord` from `CloudKit` and when plotting creator `recordName`, I can see this:

```
(lldb) po record.creatorUserRecordID.recordName
__defaultOwner__
```

but, Dashboard show a real value.

[image]

Why the difference?!

I hope I do not have to download only because of this the logged in user first?!

Answer (score 8):

`__defaultOwner__` mean's it's owned by the currently logged in iCloud account. So you could could check for that and display "Me" or the person's name if you have it. If you need to find out the logged-in user's `recordID` you can use the async method: `fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler`.

Comment: Furthermore, this can be found in the variable: CKCurrentUserDefaultName: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckcurrentuserdefaultname?language=objc

Comment: CKCurrentUserDefaultName is supported only from iOS 10.0+

Answer (score -2):

it is a bug

edit this:

```
- (void)postMoodFeed:(NSString *)moodFeed
{
    CKRecord *moodRecord = [[CKRecord alloc] initWitenter code herehRecordType:@"Mood"];
    moodRecord[@"moodFeed"] = moodFeed`enter code here`

    [[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase] saveRecord:moodRecord completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
        [self queryMyMood];
    }];
}

- (void)queryMyMood
{
    // currentUserRecordID is fetched from fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler: of CKContainer
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"creatorUserRecordID = %@", currentUserRecordID];

    CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Mood" predicate:predicate];

    [[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase] performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        if (results) {
            for (CKRecord *eachRecord in results) {
                // Following logs are all __defaultOwner__
                NSLog(@"%@", eachRecord.creatorUserRecordID.recordName);
                [[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase]fetchRecordWithID:eachRecord.creatorUserRecordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
                    // All following logs are "Unknown item" error
                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: it's not a bug. check malhal answer.