# Determining If CKRecord Was Created By Current User

Tags: ios, swift, comparison, cloud, cloudkit

I'm new to CloudKit and I was trying to figure out if a Record was created by the current user. I have researched this topic and have come about two methods to do this. I'm not sure which one is right or better and I don't even quite understand how the second method works.

The first way is using the following method to get the current user and then comparing it to the user who created the record:

```
func fetchUserRecordID(
    completionHandler: (recordID: CKRecordID?, error: CKError?) -> Void
)
```

The second way involves an extension on CKRecord:

```
extension CKRecord{
    var wasCreatedByThisUser: Bool{
        return (creatorUserRecordID == nil) || (creatorUserRecordID?.recordName == "__defaultOwner__")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first method is making another call to the server to fetch an additional record. The downside is that costs time, it counts against your monthly traffic quotas, and you have yet another async callback function that your code flow will have to account for. If you wind up calling this check a lot, you would generate a lot of unnecessary traffic to the server.

The second method is checking a value, `creatorUserRecordID`, that came with the record you already fetched. So at the time you check its value, it's all local data, no additional calls to the server and no async processing required.

Per the answer here: [creatorUserRecordID.recordName contains "__defaultOwner__" instead of UUID shown in Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502271/creatoruserrecordid-recordname-contains-defaultowner-instead-of-uuid-shown), `__defaultOwner__` is a synonym for the local user.

The second method looks to be the better choice for most scenarios I can think of.